# Passing "this" to base constructor

Tags: c#

Is there any way to pass "this" to the base constructor?

```
abstract class Base<TSelf>
{
    public ICollection<TSelf> List;

    public Base(ICollection<TSelf> list, TSelf self)
    {
        List = list;
        List.Add(self);
    }
}

class Implementation : Base<Implementation>
{
    public Implementation() : base(new List<Implementation>(), this)
    {
    }
}
```

Obviously there is a compilation error in the constructor of `Implementation` where `this` is passed to `base`.

I also do not see any way to instantiate `list` at `Base` level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't use `this` in a constructor initializer. You'd have to add call `Add(this)` afterwards - but you can do that in the `Base<TSelf>` constructor, so long as you cast to `TSelf`. You need to cast `this` to `object` first before casting to `TSelf` for fairly complicated reasons around the conversions allowed with type parameters, unfortunately.

You can create a `List<TSelf>` in the `Base` constructor though, with no problem. Here's sample code showing both of these:

```
abstract class Base<TSelf>
{
    // Let's make it a property rather than a public field...
    public ICollection<TSelf> List { get; }

    public Base()
    {
        List = new List<TSelf>();
        // This will obviously fail if you try to create a `Base<Foo>`
        // from a class that isn't a Foo
        TSelf selfThis = (TSelf) (object) this;
        List.Add(selfThis);
    }
}

class Implementation : Base<Implementation>
{
}
```

You can add a constraint to `TSelf` to make the casting failure *less likely accidentally* but not impossible:

```
abstract class Base<TSelf> where TSelf : Base<TSelf>
```

That doesn't stop you from writing

```
class Implementation : Base<Implementation> {}
class Evil : Base<Implementation> {}
```

Then when you construct an instance of `Evil`, you're trying to add an `Evil` reference to a `List<Implementation>` which can't work... and the cast fails to stop you from getting that far.

Comment: Casting `this` to `object` before casting to `TSelf` was the solution!

Comment: Regarding you comment _This will obviously fail_: can't this be enforced with a `where T : Base`?

Comment: @ManuelFaux: Yup, will mention that.

Comment: Would there be any downside if I wrote `TSelf selfThis = this as TSelf;` instead of `TSelf selfThis = (TSelf) (object) this;` after constrainig `TSelf` to `class`?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes - it means that if there's something wrong, you silently get a null reference in the list instead of an exception. I prefer early failure.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jon Skeet has said, you cannot pass `this` through a regular old constructor call. It's possible to do so using reflection and the `FormatterServices` class, however. The example code below uses the factory pattern for better readability.

---

**Base class implementation:**

```cs
public abstract class Model<TSelf>
    where TSelf : Model<TSelf>
{
    public ICollection<TSelf> Items { get; }

    protected Model(TSelf self, ICollection<TSelf> items)
    {
        if ((self == null) || (items == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (self != this)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        Items = items;
        Items.Add(self);
    }
}
```

---

**Derived class implementation:**

```cs
public sealed class ModelImplementation
    : Model<ModelImplementation>
{
    private ModelImplementation(ModelImplementation self)
        : base(self, new List<ModelImplementation>()) { }
}
```

---

The bread and butter of this technique is the `ModelFactory` class, which takes an uninitialized object and manually calls the appropriate constructor on it. Support for additional constructor parameters can be implemented by modifying the `GetConstructor` and `Invoke` calls.

You should call `ModelFactory.Create<ModelImplementation>()` to get a new `ModelImplementation` in lieu of the `new` keyword.

**Factory class implementation:**

```cs
public static class ModelFactory
{
    public static Model<TSelf> Create<TSelf>()
        where TSelf : Model<TSelf>
    {
        var result = FormatterServices
            .GetUninitializedObject(typeof(TSelf));

        result.GetType()
            .GetConstructor(
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null,
                new[] { typeof(TSelf) },
                null)
            .Invoke(
                result,
                new[] { result });

        return (TSelf)result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not commonly known, but you can easily pass a child class instance to the base class constructor without using downcasts, reflection and runtime errors.

To do so you can add an abstract method that returns `TSelf`.

See the example:

```
abstract class Base<TSelf> where TSelf : Base<TSelf>
{
    public ICollection<TSelf> List;

    public Base(ICollection<TSelf> list)
    {
        List = list;
        List.Add(GetSelf());
    }
    
    protected abstract TSelf GetSelf();
}

class Implementation : Base<Implementation>
{
    public Implementation() : base(new List<Implementation>())
    {
    }
    
    protected override Implementation GetSelf() => this;
}
```

`where TSelf : Base<TSelf>` is just the additional not the mandatory constraint.